# Hasty Pudding test vectors

Tags: test-vectors

I’ve been implementing Hasty Pudding from [its spec](http://richard.schroeppel.name:8015/hpc/hpc-spec), but I can’t find a copy of the test data to validate my implementation against.

[The directory of tests](http://richard.schroeppel.name:8015/hpc/test-index.html) links to various files in ftp://ftp.cs.arizona.edu/xkernel/rcs/hpc/test/, but that server no longer talks FTP, and I haven’t been able to find the files anywhere else. (I’ve tried HTTP on the same and similar domains, the Internet Archive, general web searches, and emailing the author, all to no avail so far.)

I also don’t have the reference implementation or any other tested implementation to compare. (The author [offers](http://richard.schroeppel.name:8015/hpc/) the source code to residents of the USA and Canada, which I presume to be an artefact of the crypto export laws of 1999 and I *think* is largely obsolete now, but I’m Australian and my email enquiry from a couple of days ago has not been responded to anyway.)

Does anyone have the original test data, or, failing that, a reference or other tested implementation?

Comment: Hiya and welcome  :-)   But why pudding specifically?

Comment: My specific reason is its bit-granularity block sizes, for format-preserving encryption; I’m working on a scheme for encrypting and stringifying sequential IDs, and having succeeded with Speck32/64 and Speck64/128 (which yield 4–6 and 8–11-character strings in my chosen base-58) I’m coming back and trying an idea I shelved earlier: encryption in disjoint domains [0, 58¹), [58¹, 58²), [58², 58³), …, [58¹⁰, 2⁶⁴) for optimally-short IDs. As far as other algorithms are concerned, the only things I’ve found that look viable are related to FF1/FF2/FF3, but I’m not touching them patent encumbered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18758043/6126446 Have you check this? You can feed them with the same values and compare the results

Comment: @JAAAY: unfortunately, that only implements HPC for blocksize 128, which means HPC-Medium with no bit masking. It can be used to confirm key expansion and blocksize 128, but nothing else. For my *particular* use case, I actually don’t use HPC-Medium at all (as you only need it for blocksizes 1–4 and 65–128, but I only want 5–64).